# Kafka Streams: What ordering guarantees are provided for state store changelog topics when using at_least_once?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

We have a stream, that writes to a logged key/value state store. We use at_least_once. Are we guaranteed, that records appear on the changelog topic in the same order in which we made changes to the statestore via the API (knowing that sometimes replays/retries will happen), or could entries on the topic end up with a different order?

E.g. if we have state store writes: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

In case no replay happen, can we then expect records on the changelog to have the same order: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

And if a replay of say 3 and 4 happens, then we might have something like: 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5

Or are there no guarantees at all, meaning we might see something like: 2, 1, 3, 5, 4 or maybe even 1, 2, 4, 5 (if 3 and 4 have the same key).

Comment: Order should be guaranteed. Note thought, that some write into the store or the changelog topic might be missing in case of failure. For each `put()` a `producer.send()` is called, but if an error occurs that is no guarantee that the `put()` was flushed to local disk (and might be lost) or if the `send()` as finished (send are async). -- but when you reprocess input data, the same put/send would be executed in the same order as before.

Comment: @Matt: As I understand you explanation, then if we have an error, then we are guaranteed, that *if* records are written to a given partition on the changelog topic, then they will be written in order without any records missing "in the middle". If any will be missing, they will be from "the tail". In other words, if 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 should have been written to a partition, but an error happens, then we might see something like 1, 2, 3 on the topic, but not something like 1, 2, 4. And if the error results in a replay from 2, then we may see 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5. Correct?

Comment: Correct. (If the producer is configures correctly.)